# Tax is not showing on Checkout Page

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, tax

My settings are set up to show price incl. VAT on Product Page, but excluding on Checkout page. VAT is not showing.
By the way, I did test order where on order confirmation VAT is showing. I have run troubleshooting for theme conflict, but the same issue appears on Twenty Twenty.
I found article: https://www.dataroots.com/no-tax-in-woocommerce-heres-the-fix/ but don't know exactly where I can check if I do miss tables. I'm not a tech person, but can add .php or custom css if needed. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVJBY.jpg)

Comment: I checked phpmyadmin and I could found 2 rows under woocommerce_tax_rate_locations table, so I believe that is not a case that table is missing as per link that I shared before.
Appreciate any other suggestions, as I holding back to launch my shop.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue what caused this [I have to clear out data of standard rate fields: (postcode/zip and city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ykFJ.jpg)